# Why does my powershell display boxed instead of chevrons?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

My powershell prompt display boxes instead of chevrons. I don't have any idea about this. Can anyone help?
I'm running windows 10 1909

[image: Powershell in Windows Terminal]

Edit: ${function:prompt}
[image]

Comment: Try changing the font in Windows Terminal

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Already tried it. No change...

Comment: What does you `prompt` function look like? `${function:prompt}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen please check edit above

Comment: @on3ss Post code not images.

Comment: @apena Not sure why you're replying to me?

Comment: my mistake, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Cascadia Code as my font but it wasn't installed, hence the missing characters replaced with boxes.